# Get target slide item [Owl Carousel 2]

Tags: owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I need to get target slide item (prev or next) depending on control arrows or swipe.

```
var slider = $('.owl-carousel');
slider.owlCarousel({
   loop: true,
   nav: true,
   items: 1,
   smartSpeed: 600
});

slider.on('change.owl.carousel', function(e) {
   console.log($('.owl-item.active').html());
   // I'm getting html of current slide, but not target slide
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
slider.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) { // Action, when a carousel has changed
    var target_index = e.property.value; // Index of target slide 
    if($.isNumeric(target_index)) { // if we swipe or clicking controls arrows (or dots) - we got numeric value, but on resize target_index is object, not a number. isNumeric need to prevent wrong value
        $('.owl-item').eq(target_index).html(); // Getting target slide HTML
    }
});
```

Comment: Max, your answer got flagged as low quality - can you just add some explanation text about the events that Owl Carousel provides? A link to that part of the docs helps too but some explanatory text is best.

Comment: Please add some explanation